# Why is ū long in "Vitruvius"?

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, names, vowel-quantity

Lewis & Short and Gaffiot's dictionaries both mark long ū in the name *[Vitrūvius](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/Vitruvius).* How do we know this, and do we know the reason for it?

In my experience, most words with the sequence -uvi- + vowel in Latin have short -ŭ-, e.g. *fluvius, pluvius, adluviō.*

I cannot find the etymology of the name, and I saw no occurrences in verse in the PHI Latin Texts corpus. There seems to be a related female name *Vitruvia.*

Comment: FWIW, Glare marks it long, too.

Comment: cf. Pācŭvĭus http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=Pacuvius

Comment: Latin stresses the anti-penultimate syllable, the third to last syllable, which would be the "tru" (Vi-**tru**-vi-us). This may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't exactly an answer, but it's something that I found about the etymology of the name. Actually, it makes me think even more that it ought to have short ŭ.

Buck's *Grammar of Oscan and Umbrian: With a Collection of Inscriptions and a Glossary* (1904) has a section discussing name-forming elements. On [page 189](https://archive.org/details/grammarofoscanum00buckuoft/page/189/mode/2up), he writes

> *-ou̯io-* in proper names. O. **Kaluvis**, Gen. Sg. **Kalúvieis**;-- U. *Fisouie, Grabouie.* U. **Ikuvinus**, *Iiuinur,* etc. also implies an **Igou̯io-*: L. *Iguvium.* Cf. Mars. *Cantouios,* and *Vitrovius, Sallovius* etc., which occur in Latin inscriptions but are dialectic, the regular Latin forms being *Vitruvius, Salluvius,* etc.
>
> Note. *-ou̯io-* is an extension of *-ou̯o-*, earlier *-eu̯o-*, as *-u̯io-* is of *-u̯o-*. For *-eu̯o-* beside  *-u̯o-*, cf. Ion. κενεός from *κενεϝός and κεινός from *κενϝός. In Latin the two forms of the suffix became identical.<sup>1</sup>
>
> [...]
>
> 1. For the material see especially Solmsen, Studieren zur lat. Lautgeschichte, pp. 135 ff., [...]

I see no reason from this etymology to give a long value to the u in *Vitrūvius*, so (assuming Buck is correct in categorizing its etymological source) the only type of evidence I think of that we could have is metrical.

Buck's mention of the proper name Salluvius (which seems to occur as a *nomen gentilicium* of Gaius Salluvius Naso, and maybe some other individuals) did lead me to another word that a dictionary shows with -ūvi-: Sal(l)ūvii (=Σάλυες) per [Gaffiot](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/gaffiot/Salluvii). However, it's equally mysterious to me how we would know the length of the vowel in this name for this people. It seems to occur with the two-l spelling (Salluuii, Salluuios, Salluiorum) in Livy and Pliny, and with the one-l spelling (Saluuii) in Florus.